# how to capture "ESC" from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

i need to capture **esc** key to close my open div.The div contents an iframe. it's works when i open the div and soon press **esc** to close it.But when i clicked the iframe,and pressed key **esc**,it's no more work for me.becuse it only capture the current window(*at this point will be the iframe window*),how can i fix it ?

Here is my parent window's code:

```
      window.onkeydown = function(e) {
           var e = e || window.event;
           if (e.keyCode === 27) {
               _this.closeDemo();
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a `onkeydown` handler inside the iframe:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        parent.closeDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I also thinking about this method.but can we find a more better Solution?